# Zariski closure of the image of an induced representation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated discrete group, $H\le G$ a subgroup of finite index $d$, and let $\rho : H\rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ be a representation.

Let $\tilde{\rho} := \operatorname{Ind}_H^G\rho$ be the induced representation. I want to say that the Zariski closures of the images of $\rho$ and $\tilde{\rho}$ have isomorphic identity components. In a formula, I want to say:
$$\overline{\tilde{\rho}(G)}^0 \cong \overline{\rho(H)}^0$$
as algebraic groups. Is something like this correct? I'm happy to assume that $H$ is normal in $G$. What's a good way to see this?

Comment: Why would you expect this?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $H$ is normal in $G$.

If $G/H$ acts non-trivially on $\rho$ by conjugation then @SashaP has given a counter-example in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445847/zariski-closure-of-the-image-of-an-induced-representation#comment1151678_445866) to this answer.

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$If $G/H$ acts trivially on $\rho$, then your guess is correct. Consider the diagonal map $\Delta : \GL_n \to \GL_{n \cdot d}$, then there exists an element $\alpha \in \GL_{nd}(\mathbb{C})$ such that
$$\Delta \circ \rho = \alpha \circ \widetilde{\rho} \rvert_{H} \circ \alpha^{-1}.$$

Since $\Delta$ is a closed map, it induces an isomorphism $\overline{\rho(H)} \cong \overline{\widetilde{\rho}(H)}$.
Now it suffices to show that $\overline{\widetilde{\rho}(H)}^\circ \cong \overline{\widetilde{\rho}(G)}^\circ$.

If $G = \bigcup_{i} g_i H$ for some $g_1, \dots, g_d \in G$, then also
$$
 \widetilde{\rho}(G) \subset \bigcup_{i} \widetilde{\rho}(g_i) \overline{\widetilde{\rho}(H)},
$$
hence
$\overline{\widetilde{\rho}(H)} \subset \overline{\widetilde{\rho}(G)}$ is a finite index subgroup. In particular, $\overline{\widetilde{\rho}(H)} \subset \overline{\widetilde{\rho}(G)}$ is open and closed. It follows that there is an isomorphism of identity components
$$
\overline{\widetilde{\rho}(H)}^{\circ} \cong \overline{\widetilde{\rho}(G)}^{\circ}
$$
as desired.

Comment: $\newcommand\r{\rho}\newcommand\tr{\widetilde\r}$I am a little confused by filling in the details here.  $\cong$ probably does not mean an isomorphism of groups, since $\r(H)\cup\dotsb\cup\r(H)$ does not carry a natural group structure.  So I think you just mean that there is a finite-index subgroup $\tr(H)$ of $\tr(G)$ that is isomorphic to $\r(H)$.  Then it is not clear to me that the cosets of $\tr(H)$ remain disjoint upon passing to the Zariski closure.  That is OK, since all you need is that the closure of $\tr(H)$ has finite index in […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1151572)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445847/zariski-closure-of-the-image-of-an-induced-representation#comment1151571_445866)$\newcommand\r{\rho}\newcommand\tr{\widetilde\r}$ the closure of $\tr(G)$; and some finite collection of copies of the closure of $\tr(H)$ covers $\tr(G)$ and is closed, hence covers the closure of $\tr(G)$.  So that is fine.  But why is the closure of $\tr(H)$ isomorphic to the closure of $\r(H)$?

Comment: You are right, the $\cong$ symbol does not refer to the group structure. It denotes homeomorphism, so it is just a topological property.

Comment: Ok I don't have an argument for why the closures stay disjoint. However, $\rho(H)$ is mapped to $\widetilde{\rho}(H)$ under the diagonal map $\mathrm{GL}_n \to \mathrm{GL}_{n \cdot d}$. So the closure of $\widetilde{\rho}(H)$ is also contained in the diagonal and isomorphic to the closure of $\rho(H)$. I will edit my answer to try to correct the proof.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445847/zariski-closure-of-the-image-of-an-induced-representation#comment1151641_445866), the reason I make a fuss about $\cong$ is because you use it twice, and the first time denotes homeomorphism, but the second time (I assume!) denotes topological isomorphism, so I think it would be a good idea to distinguish them.

Comment: Yes I agree, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Isn't the restriction of $Ind^G_H\rho$ rather isomorphic to the sum of twists of $\rho$ under the conjugation action of $G/H$? I think that situations where these twists are different give many counterexamples to the original statement. E.g if $G=Z/2\ltimes (C^{\times})^2$ with $Z/2$ swapping the factors and $H=(C^{\times})^2$, the character $(t_1,t_2)\mapsto t_1$ of $H$ has $1$-dimensional Zariski closure of the image, while the restriction of the induced representation to $H$ is $(t_1,t_2)\mapsto diag(t_1,t_2)$ and therefore has $2$-dimensional Zariski closure of the image.

Comment: @SashaP I think you are right, I made a mistake with the restriction of induction. I will correct it.

Comment: @SashaP, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445847/zariski-closure-of-the-image-of-an-induced-representation#comment1151678_445866), $(\mathbb C^\times)^2$ isn't finitely generated (right?), but I guess you could just take, say, $G = \mathbb Z/2 \ltimes \langle(\pi, 1), (1, \pi)\rangle$ or something, since we're going to close it up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be the induced representation and $W$ the $H$-subspace from which it is induced. Certainly, the Zariski closure of the image of $H$ in $GL(V)$ is of finite index in the Zariski closure of the image of $G$ in $GL(V)$. Write $V=W\oplus s_{2}W\oplus\cdots\oplus s_{n}W$, where $1,\ldots,s_{n}$ is a set of coset representatives for $H$ in $G$. Then (assuming it is normal) $H$ acts on $s_{i}W$ by the conjugate representation, and the Zariski closure of the image of $H$ in $GL(V)$ is the Zariski closure of the image of $H$ in $GL(W)$ embedded "diagonally" in $GL(W)\times\cdots\times GL(s_{n}W)\subset GL(V)$. Hence the conclusion.

Comment: How does this differ from @LambertA'Campo's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/445866)?